# Select value using VBA from IE11 dropbox

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer-11, getelementbyid, dispatchevent

I have looked everywhere for a solution and nothing works. Here is my  code:

```
Sub GetData()


Dim IE As Object
Dim ccy As Object
Dim ccy1 As Object
Dim allstatus As Object
Dim GetMTM As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'go to MTM report
IE.navigate "www.mylink.com"

'check for good connection
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
'wait for window to open
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0.00:01"))

'send login information
SendKeys "blah", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "blah"
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "blah"
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

'check for good connection
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
'wait for window to open
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0.00:01"))

'all status
Set allstatus = IE.document.getelementbyid("allstatus1")
allstatus.Click

Set ccy = IE.document.createevent("HTMLEvents")
ccy.initevent "change", True, False
Set ccy1 = IE.document.getelementbyid("currency")

ccy1.selectedindex = 9
ccy1.dispatchevent ccy 'nothing happens here!!!

'load data
Set GetMTM = IE.document.forms(0)
GetMTM.submit

End Sub
```

The issue is that i can't get the dispatchevent to work. If i step through my code using f8, i can see the drop box change to CAD but then when i submit the form, it changes back to the original value. The page never actually refreshes. I have tried every solution suggested on this site and everything works the exact same as below. FYI i am using IE11.

PS i apologize but i can't provide the link to the page

UPDATE: I now believe it is the submit form event that is not working now. If i remove for the dropdown and the checkbox click, and just try to run the form with

```
'load data
Set GetMTM = IE.document.forms(0)
GetMTM.submit
```

It won't load the form. But if i go and click on the Go button myself it works..
Here's the HTML for the submit button and check boxes

```
                <TD align="right" valign="center"><input id="matchedstatus1" name="matchedstatus" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px" onclick="javascript:changeStatus(markToMarketBean, this)" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/><input type="hidden" name="_matchedstatus" value="on"/>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD align="left" valign="center">Matched</TD>
                <TD><IMG src="/images/gtss/neutral/spacer.gif" width="12"
                    height="1"></TD>
                <TD align="right" valign="center"><input id="oursource1" name="oursource" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px" onclick="javascript:changeSource(markToMarketBean, this)" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/><input type="hidden" name="_oursource" value="on"/>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD align="left" valign="center">Ours</TD>
                <TD rowspan="2"><IMG src="/images/gtss/neutral/spacer.gif"
                    width="10" height="1"></TD>
                <TD align="left" valign="middle" rowspan="2"><input type="submit"
                    name="go" value='Go' 
                    style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px">
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD align="right" valign="center"><input id="allstatus1" name="allstatus" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px" onclick="javascript:changeStatus(markToMarketBean, this)" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_allstatus" value="on"/>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD align="left" valign="center">All</TD>
                <TD><IMG src="/images/gtss/neutral/spacer.gif" width="12"
                    height="1"></TD>
                <TD align="right" valign="center"><input id="theirsource1" name="theirsource" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px" onclick="javascript:changeSource(markToMarketBean, this)" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_theirsource" value="on"/>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD align="left" valign="center">Theirs</TD>
```

EDIT: Here's the html code for the dropbox:

```
<select id="currency" name="currency" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
            <option value="AED">AED</option><option value="ARS">ARS</option><option value="AUD">AUD</option><option value="BDT">BDT</option><option value="BGL">BGL</option><option value="BGN">BGN</option><option value="BMD">BMD</option><option value="BOB">BOB</option><option value="BRL">BRL</option><option value="CAD">CAD</option><option value="CHF">CHF</option><option value="CLP">CLP</option><option value="CNY">CNY</option><option value="COP">COP</option><option value="CYP">CYP</option><option value="CZK">CZK</option><option value="DKK">DKK</option><option value="ECS">ECS</option><option value="EEK">EEK</option><option value="EGP">EGP</option><option value="EUR">EUR</option><option value="FIM">FIM</option><option value="GBP">GBP</option><option value="GHC">GHC</option><option value="HKD">HKD</option><option value="HRK">HRK</option><option value="HUF">HUF</option><option value="IDR">IDR</option><option value="ILS">ILS</option><option value="INR">INR</option><option value="ISK">ISK</option><option value="JOD">JOD</option><option value="JPY">JPY</option><option value="KES">KES</option><option value="KRW">KRW</option><option value="KWD">KWD</option><option value="KZT">KZT</option><option value="LBP">LBP</option><option value="LKR">LKR</option><option value="LTL">LTL</option><option value="LVL">LVL</option><option value="MAD">MAD</option><option value="MUR">MUR</option><option value="MXN">MXN</option><option value="MYR">MYR</option><option value="NGN">NGN</option><option value="NOK">NOK</option><option value="NZD">NZD</option><option value="PEN">PEN</option><option value="PGK">PGK</option><option value="PHP">PHP</option><option value="PKR">PKR</option><option value="PLN">PLN</option><option value="ROL">ROL</option><option value="RUB">RUB</option><option value="SEK">SEK</option><option value="SGD">SGD</option><option value="SIT">SIT</option><option value="SKK">SKK</option><option value="THB">THB</option><option value="TND">TND</option><option value="TRL">TRL</option><option value="TRY">TRY</option><option value="TWD">TWD</option><option value="TZS">TZS</option><option value="UAH">UAH</option><option value="USD" selected="selected">USD</option><option value="VEB">VEB</option><option value="VND">VND</option><option value="ZAR">ZAR</option><option value="ZWD">ZWD</option>
```

Comment: [check out the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827461/excel-vba-ie-11-unable-to-refresh-page-after-selecting-value-in-a-dropdown) that's using a similar methodology.  I always advise against SendKeys as it is not guaranteed to send them if another event occurs while the user is running this.

Comment: Thanks @JimmySmith. I have already seen that link and tried everything on that page.. none of it works. I don;t know what else to try at this point.. or perhaps im missing a very simple/obvious piece ??

Comment: Can you share the page you are working with?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the link. The sheet is just a table of data and at the top of the data is a drop down that lets you select which currency we want the data in. 

I'm thinking the issue might be with the initevent .. maybe change isnt the event i want?

Comment: UPDATE: so if i manually go and click on the currency i want from the drop down, then go and look at the source code, the source code didn't recognize that click.. it's still the old currency. The source code only changes when I submit the form

Comment: Try click the drop down before changing the SelectedIndex? `ccy1.Click` and set the value? You can also put break points here and there so you can manually try change IE elements in Immediate Window.

Comment: clicking before changing the selectedindex didnt work. how so i change IE elements in the Immediate window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself for anyone who cares...

The issue was when I was trying to submit the form... had nothing to do with the drop down.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

Dim allstatus As Object
Dim GetMTM As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'go to MTM report
IE.navigate "wwww.mylink.com"

'check for good connection
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
'wait for window to open
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0.00:01"))

'send login information
SendKeys "blah", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "blah"
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "blah!"
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

'check for good connection
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
'wait for window to open
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0.00:01"))

'all status
Set allstatus = IE.Document.getElementById("allstatus1")
allstatus.Click

Dim evt As Object
Dim ccy As Object

Set evt = IE.Document.createevent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
Set ccy = IE.Document.getElementById("currency")
ccy.Click
ccy.Value = "CAD"
ccy.dispatchEvent evt

'========this was the line i needed to fix!!!===========
'load data
IE.Document.getElementsByName("go")(0).Click
'========================================================

'check for good connection
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
'wait for window to open
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0.00:01"))

'download data
IE.Document.getElementsByName("download")(0).Click

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```