# How to fire an event to update a web page with VBA?

Tags: jquery, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have been working in a web automation project, and the current web page I'm working with updates itself when entering a value in one of the searchboxes. However, when I enter values in the searchboxes using VBA code, the event that updates the page does not fire. Here is the code so far:

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://www.hacienda.go.cr/tica/web/hdbaranc.aspx"

Do Until objIE.Busy = False And objIE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("vVNCMINI").Value = partida & "00"
objIE.document.getElementById("vVNCMFIN").Value = partida & "00"
'Fire the event here
```

What I have tried so far is using `.Click` on a searchbox, and firing an `onChange` event like it was suggested here: [Excel VBA & IE 11 - Unable to refresh page after selecting value in a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827461/excel-vba-ie-11-unable-to-refresh-page-after-selecting-value-in-a-dropdown), but neither worked. So, any ideas what could I do?

Edit: What I did try that worked was using `Application.SendKeys` and sending enter on a searchbox. However, that only works when `objIE.visible = True`, and I set that to `True` only when debugging. I want it to be set to `False` but then the enter key is sent to the excel workbook, not to IE.

Comment: Have you tried sending a `POST` or other web query through vba, then programming the website to respond to that specific `POST` as well?

Comment: I haven't, and also I have no idea how to do that, never heard of something like that. Can you illustrate me please? Maybe that could work.

Comment: Ah, the website is not under your control is it?  It may be very difficult to get the website to do what you need it to if you don't know the underlying code of the website itself.  Also, I can tell you how to send a POST request from vba, but once it comes to jquery, I'm unfortunately out of my depth (hence the comment instead of an answer).

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know the code of the website. Thanks for the idea anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following example. This is working on my end with IE11 by firing the event manually. I cleaned up the code somewhat, and I hard coded the values as I wasn't sure where the variable `partida` is coming from.

---

**Edit**

If the onChange event isn't working for some reason, try the code below. It will submit the form data instead. That should trigger a new page load.

---

**Code**

```
Private Sub SOExample()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.hacienda.go.cr/tica/web/hdbaranc.aspx"

        Do Until .Busy = False And .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .Document.getElementById("vVNCMINI").Value = "1002"
        .Document.getElementById("vVNCMFIN").Value = "12400"

        'Submit the form
        .Document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It actually does not work properly, sometimes when ie is still open, it works but if it is closed is does not work. The website is pretty confusing, its hard to identify which event actually loads the data.

Comment: You may need to establish a new reference to the IE object, then fire the event again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it still doesn't work for me. Isn't there a way to simulate the press of a key or something like that aside from `SendKeys`? Maybe something simple like that could work.

Comment: What isn't working? The above code should work. Are you saying it doesn't work when the visibility is set to False? More detail on what isn't working would be helpful. You can always try Selenium, or use a webrequest.

Comment: Visibility is set to True, and when I add `.document.getElementById("vVNCMFIN").FireEvent ("onChange")` still nothing happens, the event is not fired. I have been trying other ways to fire events, and firing different events like "keyPress" or "keyDown", but with no success. Maybe as @UGP mentioned, there is another event that loads the data that I am missing.

Comment: The events fire, but those events dont actually update the data in the table. i tried to find the event, that actually does it without success. This website is very strangely coded.

Comment: @UGP thanks for the help, it seems I should find another way to get the data I need, or maybe just stick with `Application.SendKeys`. Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: Worked to perfection. You deserve a piece of heaven.